# Service Fabric in VS2015, PowerShell script failed to execute

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I'm doing the Service Fabric tutorial that can be found here:

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-create-your-first-application-in-visual-studio/
```

I started PowerShell (in Windows 10 running in Parallels through OS X) as administrator an executed this according to instructions:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

I have started Visual Studio 2015 both as admin and normally. I then started the tutorial app, but I'm getting the following error:

```
The PowerShell script failed to execute. See the Output window for details.
```

The output window just gives this:

```
2>Finished executing script 'Set-LocalClusterReady'.
2>Time elapsed: 00:00:03.1922793
2>The PowerShell script failed to execute.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas to what could be wrong?

UPDATE: I actually get the following error:

```
2>EnsureAdminPrivileges : Not running as administrator. You need to run Visual Studio with administrator privileges
```

Which is strange because I have started VS as administrator...

Comment: Did you try the options from this page? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-troubleshoot-local-cluster-setup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error in VS17 RC as well as *Unable to determine whether the application is installed on the cluster or not*. It seemed as if the deployment of the local cluster had some issues.

What solved it for me was to run *Repair* from the Visual Studio setup.

After repairing, the cluster deployed as expected and I had no more error messages.

Comment: Is this the Repair option in Visual Studio Installer?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the solution was that **I first needed to close Visual Studio** and the  **run it as an administrator**.

Very simple solution to an annoying error.